# CSS to target div that contains specific attributre or tag?

Tags: html, css, attributes

I'm working with a POS system that generates a website.  Large parts of the code are proprietary and thus I can't edit a lot of things.

I have an outputted category listing that floats some images as categories.  I want to hide the first 3 listed on the main page.  I tried targeting the containing div with **div:nth-child(1)**, *which worked*, but each sub-page it also hides them as well.

Unfortunately ALL non-main pages have only ONE class added to the body and main divs so I can't do a per-category ID or style, or per-page.

What I *do* have is an image tag that will be the same on each page.  So I have tried the following:

```
img[src="theimage.png"] {
display: none; 
}
```

This also works great, **BUT** it only hides the image.  Is there any way I can target the surrounding divs using that code or a variation of that code?  For reference here is a basic structure:

```
<div class="cCategoryDivContainer col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
     <div class="cCategoryDiv">
         <div class="cItemTitleDiv">
             <p class="cCategoryTitle">Category Title</p>
         </div>
         <div class="cItemImageDiv">
             <span class="cItemImageHelper"></span>
             <a href="#"><img class="cItemImage" src="theimage.png"></a>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Essentially I want to target the div with class **cCategoryDivContainer** ***IF*** the src of the inside image is set to *theimage.png*.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you can in modern browsers.
See support: https://caniuse.com/?search=has

```css
.cCategoryDiv:has(img[src="theimage.png"]) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="cCategoryDivContainer col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
     <div class="cCategoryDiv">
         <div class="cItemTitleDiv">
             <p class="cCategoryTitle">Category Title</p>
         </div>
         <div class="cItemImageDiv">
             <span class="cItemImageHelper"></span>
             <a href="#"><img class="cItemImage" src="theimage.png"></a>
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class="cCategoryDiv">
         <div class="cItemTitleDiv">
             <p class="cCategoryTitle">Category Title</p>
         </div>
         <div class="cItemImageDiv">
             <span class="cItemImageHelper"></span>
             <a href="#"><img class="cItemImage" src="anotherimage.png"></a>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```